# How to create custom popup without any click event?

Tags: javascript

Here is my sample code with default alert box.. Like this i want to create an custom alert box without any click event..

Default alert box : https://jsfiddle.net/NithyaRubini/m35m9xv9/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body onLoad="value();">
   <script>
 function value()
{
   var a = "apple";
    if (a == "apple")
    {
    alert("hi");
    }
}
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: are you looking for a modal type?

Comment: You want to design your own popup?

Comment: you can describe more about your problem so that one can solve it easiely .

Comment: use [jQuery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and it's [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: Yes i want to design my own pop up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a Javascript Modal. You can customize it anyway you want and trigger it on document ready.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">x</span>
  <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   modal.style.display = "block";
});
```

Here's a link to the w3 schools example:
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FACIUK0W64HW

Comment: Thank you so much.. But what i want to do is. Without any click event i want to show the popup..

Comment: that's cool. that's why i am triggering the modal on $( document ).ready .

Comment: I've edited my answer to have a different w3schools example with a small tweak, I'm triggering the modal on document load. @Nithya Please check the same.

Comment: :) Great. Please accept/upvote the answer if it works for you.